# React Native Custom Font Extra Padding

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, native

I am using a custom font (Cairo) for both Android & IOS. The font rendered with an extra padding for both platforms like the following

[image: sample one]

When I tried to set `lineHeight=[fontSize]` I got the following

[image: sample two]

I tried to set `lineGap=0` following this article:
[Consistent font line height rendering](https://medium.com/@martin_adamko/consistent-font-line-height-rendering-42068cc2957d)
but I find that it's already ZERO

Also tried the paddingTop solution but it's not working at all just shift the text down with the bottom space like the above images

Hope anyone can help :)

Comment: try setting the height as well as line-height

Comment: the same issue :(

Comment: considering your answer is exactly what i suggested are you sure its the same issue? ;P

Comment: @JohnRuddell hhhh, yeah you are right :), setting height is yours and (lineHeight: font-size * 1.4) is mine ;P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up doing something like that:

```
fontSize: 15,
lineHeight: 15 * 1.4,
height: 15
```

Unconvinced with a solution like that but it's the only thing that makes it work o_O

If I get a better solution I will update the question :)

Comment: Unfortunately is not a good answer (but yes, as work-around is acceptable) because you increase the line spacing between rows of multiline text

Comment: Why is the multiplier set to `1.4`?

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked to set `includeFontPadding: false` in styles:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props#includefontpadding-android